# Scala's compile-time type constant to use pattern matching

Tags: scala, types

I'm using algebraic data types (case objects) to represent types to use them in pattern maching.

```
sealed trait PrimitiveType
case object IntType extends PrimitiveType
case object LongType extends PrimitiveType
case object StringType extends PrimitiveType
...

def valueType(key: String): PrimitiveType = {
  "NAME" => StringType
  "AGE" => IntType
  ...
}

def read(db: Database, key: String): Unit = valueType(key) match {
  case IntType => send(db.parseIntField(database, key))
  case LongType => send(db.parseLongField(database, key))
  case StringType => send(db.parseStringField(database, key))
  ...
}
```

But you know, there are already `Int`, `Long`, `String`, and so on in Scala.
I think it is a waste to define several case objects to represent these.
I want to change `IntType`, `LongType`, ... to `Int.type`, `Long.type` or whatever I can use in pattern matching.

What's efficient in this case?
There are `classOf`, `typeOf`, `TypeTag`, `ClassManifest`, ... but I can't see exact difference among them.

I'm using Scala 2.11, so `TypeTag`s are OK if it is effective in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this case (i.e. you are only dealing with primitive types and don't care about generics) all of them would work fine. Except there's no point using Manifests in new projects. E.g. with typetags:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

val TypeTagString = typeTag[String]

def valueType(key: String): TypeTag[_] = {
  "NAME" => TypeTagString
  "AGE" => TypeTag.Int
  ...
}

def read(db: Database, key: String): Unit = valueType(key) match {
  case TypeTag.Int => send(db.parseIntField(database, key))
  case TypeTag.Long => send(db.parseLongField(database, key))
  case TypeTagString => send(db.parseStringField(database, key))
  ...
}
```

However, I'd consider going back to the original design and changing it a bit:

```
sealed trait PrimitiveType[T] {
  def parseField(db: Database, key: String): T
}
case object IntType extends PrimitiveType[Int] {
  def parseField(db: Database, key: String) = db.parseIntField(key)
}
...

def read(db: Database, key: String): Unit = valueType(key).parseField(db, key)
```

Comment: cool. one more thing to fix though: there exists no `TypeTag.String`

Comment: @ShyamendraSolanki `TypeTag.XXX` is only for primitives; the general syntax, and the only one for a reference type, is `typeTag[String]`.

Comment: @ShyamendraSolanki Ugh, fixed again. On the other hand, your own version is also incorrect: in `case typeTagString`, `typeTagString` is just a variable and will match anything :) You need to either capitalize it, or surround it with backticks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TypeTag objects and pattern matching as follows:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

val TypeTagString = typeTag[String]

def valueType(key: String): TypeTag[_] = key match {
    case "NAME" => typeTag[String]
    case "AGE" => TypeTag.Int
}

def read(key: String): Unit = valueType(key) match {
    case TypeTag.Int => println("It is an Int") 
    case TypeTagString => println("It is a String")
                          // replaced db access with println for simplicity.
}
```

But fundamentally there is no advantage in using typetags here. It is similar to:

```
def valueTypes(key: String): Any = key match {
    case "NAME" => "NAME"
    case "AGE" => 0
}

def read(key: String): Unit = valueTypes(key) match {
    case 0 => println("It is an Int")
    case "NAME" => println("It is a String")
}
```

or simply:

```
def read(key: String): Unit = key match {

    case "NAME" | "COUNTRY" | ... => println("A string")
    case "AGE" => println("An Int")
}
```